# Flutter PickImage Not Change without reload page

Tags: flutter, image, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I try to show a random pick(asset image) on load my app.
I can show the default image on the app load screen. I give name images like image1, image2, image3...image6. When is app loading I call a random number between 1-6 and its calls an image in these 6 images.

But I want to take permission from to users change custom images.

In the options screen, I show all of this six pictures and users can click on the screen and change the image that they want to their pics.

```
        import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:persentilizlem/util/database_helper.dart';
    import 'package:persentilizlem/util/girisresimmodel.dart';
    import 'package:persentilizlem/util/imagepick_test.dart';
    import 'package:persentilizlem/util/widgets/progressindicator.dart';
    
    class PickImageSet extends StatefulWidget {
     const  PickImageSet( {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<PickImageSet> createState() => _PickImageSetState();
    
    }
    
    class _PickImageSetState extends State<PickImageSet> {
      late DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
      File? image;
      final singleImagePick = ImagePicker();
      ImageCache _imageCache =  MyImageCache();
      
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
        super.initState();
      }
    /////// Show image in screen
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SizedBox(
            height: double.maxFinite,
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder(
                      future: _databaseHelper.girisResimListesi(),
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<GirisResim>> snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Expanded(
                              child: GridView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                                  gridDelegate:
                                      const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                          crossAxisCount: 2),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                      decoration: containerBoxDecoration(),
                                      child: snapshot.connectionState ==
                                              ConnectionState.active
                                          ? Icon(
                                              Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                                            )
                                          : InkWell(
                                              onTap: () async {
                                                ImageSource? source =
                                                    await pickImageSource(context);
                                                (source != null)
                                                    ? pickImage(source,
                                                        snapshot.data![index].id)
                                                    : null;
                                                _imageCache;
                                                setState(() {});
    
                                              },
                                              child: Stack(
                                                alignment:
                                                    AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
                                                children: [
                                                  snapshot.data![index].isAsset == 0
                                                      ? Image.asset(
                                                          snapshot.data![index]
                                                              .resimYol,
                                                          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                                        )
                                                      : Image.file(
                                                          File(snapshot.data![index]
                                                              .resimYol),
                                                          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                                                        ),
                                                  Icon(
                                                    Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                                                    color: Colors.black
                                                        .withOpacity(0.3),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                    );
                                  }));
                        } else {
                          return const ProgressBar();
                        }
                      }),
                  const Text(
                      "Giriş kısmında görünen resimleri istediğiniz 6 resim ile değiştirebilirsiniz")
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      ///// for image container decoration
      BoxDecoration containerBoxDecoration() {
        return BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(style: BorderStyle.solid, width: 0.3),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: const Offset(0, 3),
              )
            ]);
      }
    
      ///// pick image from source (camera or gallery)
      Future<ImageSource?> pickImageSource(BuildContext context) async {
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          return showCupertinoModalPopup(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => CupertinoActionSheet(
              title: const Text("İmage Kaynağı"),
              actions: [
                CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(ImageSource.camera),
                    child: const Text("Kamera")),
                CupertinoActionSheetAction(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(ImageSource.gallery),
                    child: const Text("Galeri")),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                          title: const Text("Kamera"),
                          onTap: () =>
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(ImageSource.camera)),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: const Icon(Icons.image),
                          title: const Text("Galeri"),
                          onTap: () =>
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(ImageSource.gallery)),
                    ],
                  ));
        }
      }
    

        ///// for take image from source copy file app directory and write database
      Future<void> pickImage(ImageSource source, int? id) async {
        try {
          File image =  File((await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source,maxWidth: 250))!.path);
          if (image == null) return null;
          final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
         final filebuster = await image.copy("${directory.path}/giris$id.jpeg");
          GirisResim resimdata =
          GirisResim(id: id!, resimYol: filebuster.path, isAsset: 1);
          _databaseHelper.girisResimGuncelle(resimdata);
    
          setState(() {
           this.image = File(resimdata.resimYol);
          });
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print(e);
        }
      }
    /*
//// I try empty cache
      Future<void> _deleteCacheDir() async {
        final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    
        if (cacheDir.existsSync()) {
          cacheDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
        }
      }
    
      Future<void> _deleteAppDir() async {
        final appDir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    
        if(appDir.existsSync()){
          appDir.deleteSync(recursive: true);
        }
      }
    */
    
    }
```

In my code I pickImage and rename like resim1- resim2.... and I write image path in sqflite database.

Users can change default image without problem but they cannot change costumes image with different costume image without error code. Some times if user quit to app page and re-enter option page image change but I cannot change  without quit page.

[I can show 6 pics on screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLDZp.png)

Comment: Is there any suggest

Answer (score 0):

Create  a state variable for future,

```
late final dbFuture = _databaseHelper.girisResimListesi();
```

And use it on `future:`

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: dbFuture,
```

You can check 
[Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg)

Comment: It's didn't work

Comment: try to pass setState on `pickImage`

Comment: I use it already.

Comment: Sorry I think I phrased my problem wrong. I can change first default asset pictures but I can only change it once. Error when re-changing the image I changed for the 2nd time